# DEVISE after_inactive_sign_up_path_for not being called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

Environment: RAILS 3.2 + DEVISE for auth + Invitable + Confirmable add-ons.

```
Using devise (2.2.3) 
Using devise-i18n (0.6.5) 
Using devise_invitable (1.0.3)
```

I am trying to redirect to a specific location after ACCEPT (TO SIGN UP), but only `after_sign_in_path_for` seems to be called after SIGN IN and ACCEPT.

I haven't been able to have `after_accept_path_for` working. 
It continues to redirect to the "after sign in" location.

HERE THE CODE

In my routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, 
     :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations', :invitations => 'invitations' }
```

`rake routes` give me this:

```
           new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                          devise/sessions#new
               user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                          devise/sessions#create
       destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                         devise/sessions#destroy
              user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                         devise/passwords#create
          new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                     devise/passwords#new
         edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                    devise/passwords#edit
                            PUT    /users/password(.:format)                         devise/passwords#update
   cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                           registrations#cancel
          user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                                  registrations#create
      new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                          registrations#new
     edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                             registrations#edit
                            PUT    /users(.:format)                                  registrations#update
                            DELETE /users(.:format)                                  registrations#destroy
          user_confirmation POST   /users/confirmation(.:format)                     devise/confirmations#create
      new_user_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation/new(.:format)                 devise/confirmations#new
                            GET    /users/confirmation(.:format)                     devise/confirmations#show
     accept_user_invitation GET    /users/invitation/accept(.:format)                devise/invitations#edit
            user_invitation POST   /users/invitation(.:format)                       devise/invitations#create
        new_user_invitation GET    /users/invitation/new(.:format)                   devise/invitations#new
                            PUT    /users/invitation(.:format)                       devise/invitations#update
```

In my registration controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # clear session
  def create
    super
    session[:omniauth] = nil unless @user.new_record?
  end

  #protected
  # after_sign_up_path_for doesn't seem to be called when using Confirmable module
   # def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
   #   #me_path
   #   session[:user_return_to].nil? ? me_path : session[:user_return_to]
   # end

  private

  def build_resource(*args)
    super
    if session[:omniauth]
      @user.apply_omniauth(session[:omniauth])
      @user.valid?
    end
  end
end
```

Also

```
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  protected 
  def after_accept_path_for
    session[:user_return_to].nil? ? me_path : session[:user_return_to]
  end
end
```

In my application controller, (I left intentionally some commented code I tried to make it work):

```
  def store_location
      session[:user_return_to] = request.fullpath
  end

  #   def after_sign_up_path_for
  #     me_path
  #   end 
  #   
  #   def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #     me_path
  #     #session[:user_return_to].nil? ? me_path : session[:user_return_to]
  #   end

  # https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration)
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    me_path
    #dashboard_path
    #session[:user_return_to].nil? ? dashboard_path : session[:user_return_to]
  end
```

Any suggestions?

ADDED DEBUGGIN REDIRECTS

Add this to my application_controller

```
  def redirect_to_with_logging(*args) 
    logger.debug "Redirect: #{args.inspect} from #{caller[0]}" 
    redirect_to_without_logging *args 
  end 

  alias_method_chain :redirect_to, :logging
```

After Sign in, works like a charm

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-25 14:20:04 +0200
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
    [... I removed some of the Session creation info ...]
Redirect: ["/dashboard"] from /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:135:in `redirect_to'
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/dashboard
Completed 302 Found in 968ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

DOCS:

[After sign in](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in)

[After sign up](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-%28registration%29)

[After Accept](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable#integration-in-a-rails-application)   <====

Comment: Do you have `sign_up` controller method? You may put there `redirect_to my_specific_url` at the end, to redirect after signing up

Comment: Ted, I am using DEVISE, it does have a couple of hook for redirects. I didn't overwrite the sign_up method, and I don't need to. So I virtually don't have this method

Comment: Ted, I think you are right. sign_up is actually a call to the registration::create method! I'll be testing that. I think the problem comes from the method overwrite ... You should add an answer rather than a comment So I can close the question if you suggestions works.  ;) thx for the tip.

Comment: btw, you need to upgrade your devise invitable, for that version of devise you are using.. 1.0.3 is really old

Comment: its hard to debug it when you say "its not working".. what is working? use    `def redirect_to_with_logging(*args)
     logger.debug "Redirect: #{args.inspect} from #{caller[0]}"
     redirect_to_without_logging *args
   end
   alias_method_chain :redirect_to, :logging`
 in application controller to tell you what is redirecting to where

Comment: Nick this piece of code was extremely useful. You see I am probably stating the issue wrongly. I am actually not signing up. I am using Devise Invitable module (I am not allowing open Sign Up, only on invitation). So I suppose that the redirect should be on Accept http://localhost:3000/users/invitation/accept?invitation_token=pCFr19saBeFuZKqd96B9  I will have to reformulate the whole question correctly. Thx for the code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override after_accept_path_for in Invitations controllers

```
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  protected 
  def after_accept_path_for(resource)
    me_path
  end
end
```

IMPORTANT:

put this file in 'controllers/users' directory

Fix the routes.rb to use the `Users::InvitationsController`

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations', :invitations => 'users/invitations' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may put `redirect_to my_specific_url` at the end of `sign_up` controller's method, to redirect after signing up

Comment: I tried a redirect in the Registration::create method and that didn't do the trick.

Comment: @joelmaranhao, and `after_sign_up_path_for` method is not triggered in your registration controller?

Comment: No, not triggered. I tried again today to make sure. I found out that this happens because I am using the Confirmable module which requires to use after_inactive_sign_up_path_for instead. Yet that one is not triggered either.

Comment: @joelmaranhao, what's your `RegistrationsController::create` method purpose?

Comment: I am using OmniAuth ... I also allow users to authenticate with facebook and linkedIn